# Hybrid App Android and ios version compatibility

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, version-control, compatibility

I'm using `ionic` framework for mobile hybrid app.

> How can I come to know Android and ios version compatibility.

Example:
Does my App work android 4.0 (kitkat) and ios 7.0?

In `ionic` platform.json file I have this code:

```
{
    "browser": "4.1.0",
    "ios": "4.1.1",
    "android": "5.1.1"
}
```

According to this code.
Does my app work `ios` 4.1.1 and above and for `android` 5.1.1 and above?